# ADB2C custom policy - redirect to source page once signed in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have created a custom policy for signin and another for sign up. What I would like to do is send my users back to their original source page once they have hit the callback from the policy.

E.g. If they were on a blog page */some-article* and hit signin, I would like them to end up back here, rather than just at the base callback url.

I couldn't see any clear way to send in data to a custom policy and return it so I can parse it at the call back. Or if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD B2C supports the state parameter. You can use this for whatever you want. I generally use it to save the last visited url via base64encoding.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow

Comment: Thanks. What would be the purpose/benefit of the base64encoding in this case?

Comment: The benefit would be that the url encoding can get messed up because of special characters like spaces etc.. base64encoding will ensure the state translates properly. I had this problem before and needed to urldecode multiple times before being able to process it.

Comment: Right that makes sense. Been through that decoding hell recently too!

Comment: My web project is using the slightly older Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect package. From what I understand, it automatically handles the route for /account/signin so how would you go about setting and retrieving the state property using this? (It seems like it sets some internal value for state too)